# How can I use the SFCGAL version of ST_Union?

Tags: postgis, sfcgal

I'm trying to combine a bunch of geometry boundaries to get the linework of their borders, but I'm getting an error with the default, GEOS-based `ST_Union`:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom)) FROM my_table;
```

gives

```
ERROR: GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (391229 4.79279e+06, 391444 4.79279e+06) and LINESTRING (391444 4.79279e+06, 391229 4.79279e+06) at 391437.43387050979 4792789.729486906
```

According to the [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal), SFCGAL has a version of `ST_Union` that I can use:

> Some SFCGAL functions replace standard ones (ST_Intersects, ST_Intersection, ST_Difference, ST_Union, ST_Area and ST_Distance), to switch between standard functions and SFCGAL function use:
>
> ```
> SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;
> ```

However, this has no effect:

```
SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;
SHOW postgis.backend;
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom)) FROM my_table;
```

> ```
> 0 Rows Affected
>
> postgis_backend
> ----------------
> sfcgal
>
> ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (391229 4.79279e+06, 391444 4.79279e+06) and LINESTRING (391444 4.79279e+06, 391229 4.79279e+06) at 391437.43387050979 4792789.729486906
> ```

Based on the fact I'm still getting a *GEOS* error, I'm presuming it's not actually using the SFCGAL function.

The array version of `ST_Union` produces the same result:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ARRAY_AGG(ST_Boundary(geom))) FROM my_table;
```

How can I get PostGIS to invoke the SFCGAL version of `ST_Union`?

---

Note that I *do* have SFCGAL installed:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

> ```
> POSTGIS="2.5.1 r17027" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 673b9939" SFCGAL="1.2.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/25" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" RASTER
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension WHERE extname LIKE '%sfcgal%';
```

> ```
> extname        | extversion | extconfig
> ---------------+------------+-----------
> postgis_sfcgal | 2.5.1      | NULL
> ```

PostgreSQL Version:

```
SELECT version();
```

> ```
> PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
> ```

---

<sub>Aside: I don't know if the SFCGAL function will help with my error, and that's not really the topic of this question. I just want to try using to see if it does or not.</sub>

Comment: This is very odd. I understood that the sfcgal versions were to add the 3D versions of these functions, however, having looked at the source code, I can see that both 2D and 3D versions are supported.  Irrespective, such errors are usually caused by spurious decimal places and can often be fixed by using ST_SnapToGrid on the geometry before ST_Union is called.

Comment: @JohnPowell Yeah, I've tried all manner of things to fix these errors. Snapping, grid snapping, buffer/reverse buffer to remove tiny protrusions/insets. (I was told that my data is a mess and should be cleaned up, but unfortunately, neither my company nor our client has the resources to do that.) Even e-mailed the PostGIS mailing list some years back. Never could get a reliable answer. I have some really nasty code that dumps out all the line segments and tries to stitch them together one at a time, but it's not reliably producing the correct result.

Comment: How much data do you have? I don't want to sounds preachy, but, perhaps it might be a good idea to figure out what the problem with your data are, garbage in/ garbage out, and all that :D.  I would be happy to have a quick look, if you could share enough data to replicate the problem?